# Laravel way to get model using method on related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have setup relations for Mall and City model in this way:

Mall model:

```
public function city() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

City model:

```
public function malls() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'App\Mall' );
}
```

I have a method in City class with returns all cities in nearby radius:

```
public function getNearby($lat, $long, $r) {
   // return array of id of cities in $r radius
}
```

When I want to get all malls in nearby cities, I do something like this:

```
function getMallsInNearby() {
    $city_ids = City::getNearby($lat, $long, $r');
    $all_malls = Mall::all();
    foreach ( $all_malls as $mall ) {
        $malls[] = (in_array($mall->city->id , $city_ids) ? $mall : null);
    }
    return array_filter($malls);
}
```

I tried to use whereHas() method on malls and city without any success.
What is the best way to achieve this in Laravel with Eloquent relations?

Comment: You have a typo here `getNearby($lat, $long, $r');` you have extra single quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use whereIn()...

```
$city_ids = City::getNearby($lat, $long, $r');
$malls = Mall::whereIn('city_id', $city_ids);
```

Check out the docs... you can do pretty much anything... https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Hope this helps

Comment: This is pretty much all you need. Scratch whatever I tried to do in my answer.